# Linux 'screen' command to get back to the original screen

Tags: linux

I'm a newbie to Linux and am trying to create multiple instances in Linux [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

Here is what I do from the main terminal,

```
screen -S screen1
screen -S screen2
```

And from any terminal, if I list `screen -list`, it gives me all the available instances of `screen`.

So, if I want to go to a particular instance of `screen` I do,

For example:

```
screen -r screen2
```

1. What would be the screen name of my original terminal?
2. As per the document, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - closes an instance of `screen`, but how can I close the screen session itself?

Comment: This is not a programming question and belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, it's (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>). As in [detach](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Detach.html).

If you want to close the session, then it probably is
[Power-Detach](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Power-Detach.html#Power-Detach) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>)

Or

[Quit](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Quit.html#Quit) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) to kill everything.

Answer (score 0):

Type `exit` in the `screen` instance. That will close the `screen` instance. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> will detach from the `screen` instance you are currently in -> you will return to the terminal where you opened the first screen.

Think of a screen as a virtual terminal.

Your original terminal has no screen name, at it is not a screen, but the "real" terminal.

Comment: Isn't `exit` only for a shell window? If `irssi` (IRC client) has been launched instead of Bash, it will not exit (instead, `/exit`).